# Error while trying to use GCP VM Instance with TPU VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I created a VM instance in GCP with Pytorch XLA environment.
And I created a TPU-VM with `tpu-vm-pt-2.0`.

I SSHed into the VM instance and activated the conda environment with pytorch-xla. But, when I try to test a sample script to test for TPU, returns an error as follows:

```
\2023-04-17 19:35:38.550666: F    5184 tensorflow/compiler/xla/xla_client/xrt_computation_client.cc:1362\] Non-OK-status: session.Run({tensorflow::Output(result, 0)}, &outputs) status: UNIMPLEMENTED: method "RunStep" not implemented
\*\*\* Begin stack trace \*\*\*
tsl::CurrentStackTrace()
xla::XrtComputationClient::InitializeAndFetchTopology(std::string const&, int, std::string const&, tensorflow::ConfigProto const&)
xla::XrtComputationClient::InitializeDevices(std::unique_ptr\<tensorflow::tpu::TopologyProto, std::default_delete\<tensorflow::tpu::TopologyProto\> \>)
xla::XrtComputationClient::XrtComputationClient(xla::XrtComputationClient::Options, std::unique_ptr\<tensorflow::tpu::TopologyProto, std::default_delete\<tensorflow::tpu::TopologyProto\> \>)
xla::ComputationClient::Create()

        xla::ComputationClient::Get()
    
    
        PyCFunction_Call
        _PyObject_MakeTpCall
        _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    
    
        _PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict
        _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        _PyFunction_Vectorcall
    
    
    
        _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName
        PyEval_EvalCode
    
    
    
        PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags
    
        Py_BytesMain
        __libc_start_main

        End stack trace 

Aborted\
```

Can someone help me debug?

I tried the quickstart guides and the pytorch tutorials from the documentations, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. For instance, I also tried with both my VM instance and TPU instance with the same zone but still the error. I tried running the code as `XRT_TPU_CONFIG="tpu_worker;0;{IP_ADDRESS}:8470" python test.py` too, but still the error.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using tpu-vm-pt-2.0, it is recommended that you use PjRt runtime. What ACCELERATOR_TYPE are you using? depending on that you might need to follow differen guides. Can you please test if the resnet example works following the steps here? https://github.com/pytorch/xla/blob/master/docs/pjrt.md#tpu

Comment: I tried with PJRT too, same error. I tried testing adding two tensors when this error happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [TPU Node](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture-tpu-vm#tpu-node) architechture, you can try switching to [TPU VM](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture-tpu-vm#tpu-vm). TPU VM architecture is recommended over TPU Node, easier to use and faster. Here is the guide to create and run TPU VM: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/run-calculation-pytorch#tpu-vm

Comment: I am using TPU-VM architecture! The above results in TPU-VM as well.